# Cannot install programs in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lts

I get this pop up each time I try to download some program online!

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Details

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: Instead of downloading VLC from somewhere that may or may not package it for Trusty, just get it from trusty-backports.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to install using the command `dpkg --install`, please use gdebi instead.

**First**, you need to download gdebi using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

**Next**, you'll need to use gdebi to install the .deb file:

```
sudo gdebi whateverfilehere.deb
```

Works for me like a charm. Good luck!

**PS: Alternative solution**
You can also try to install the missing packages manually like:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-nox
sudo apt-get install libc6
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6
...
```